# NTFS Compression by file extension

Tags: windows, ntfs, compression

Can I enable NTFS compression on a disk, based on file extension?

I mean, that I don't want these files compressed: *.hc, *.mkv, *.mp4, *.ogg, *.7z, *.zip, *.odt, *.docx, *.png, *.jpg but I want these files compressed *.doc, *.txt, *.bmp

Is there somewhere such a feature in windows, or I must write a script to do it recursively?

Comment: You can compress individual files and individual folders, but I don't think NTFS supports compression based on extension, unless you create a script that does this for you.

Comment: Windows is smart enough to not compress files on disk when doing so is useless, such as would be the case with zip files, but of course it does mean wasting CPU time checking whether it can compress the blocks of data first.